# Dos valores en una misma columna

Tags: mysql

Hola a todos tengo el siguiente programa :

```
SELECT "resource"."name" "EMPLEAT",
"attendance"."name" "DATA", 
"attendance"."action" "ACCIO",
"hr_action_reason"."name" "MOTIU", 
"hr_timesheet_sheet_sheet"."date_to" "FULL" 

FROM "public"."hr_attendance" "attendance" 

INNER JOIN "public"."hr_employee" "employee" ON "attendance"."employee_id" = "employee"."id" 

INNER JOIN "public"."resource_resource" "resource" ON "employee"."resource_id" = "resource"."id" 

LEFT JOIN "public"."hr_action_reason" "hr_action_reason" ON "attendance"."action_desc" = "hr_action_reason"."id"

LEFT JOIN "public"."hr_timesheet_sheet_sheet" "hr_timesheet_sheet_sheet" ON "attendance"."sheet_id" = "hr_timesheet_sheet_sheet"."id"
```

Necesito que la columna:  "hr_timesheet_sheet_sheet"."date_to" "FULL"

Aparte del date_to me muestre el date_from.. pero como puedo hacerlo para que me lo muestra en el mismo sitio? Es decir me debería mostrar dos fechas.. Consigo una pero no las 2..

Gracias!

Comment: Si es sólo eso, en MySQL puedes usar `CONCAT` o `CONCAT_WS`. Ejemplo: `CONCAT ("hr_timesheet_sheet_sheet"."date_to", 'unseparadorcualquiera', "hr_timesheet_sheet_sheet"."date_from") AS FULL,  ... columnas siguientes si hubiere ` Ver:     https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editando tu consulta quedaría algo como lo siguiente:

```
SELECT "resource"."name" "EMPLEAT",
"attendance"."name" "DATA", 
"attendance"."action" "ACCIO",
"hr_action_reason"."name" "MOTIU", 
CONCAT_WS(" ", "hr_timesheet_sheet_sheet"."date_to", "hr_timesheet_sheet_sheet"."date_from") AS "FULL" 
FROM "public"."hr_attendance" "attendance" 
INNER JOIN "public"."hr_employee" "employee" ON "attendance"."employee_id" = "employee"."id" 
INNER JOIN "public"."resource_resource" "resource" ON "employee"."resource_id" = "resource"."id" 
LEFT JOIN "public"."hr_action_reason" "hr_action_reason" ON "attendance"."action_desc" = "hr_action_reason"."id"
LEFT JOIN "public"."hr_timesheet_sheet_sheet" "hr_timesheet_sheet_sheet" ON "attendance"."sheet_id" = "hr_timesheet_sheet_sheet"."id"
```

Se utiliza la función CONCAT_WS que sirve para concatenar con un separador.
Tiene 3 parámetros los cuales son:

- Separador. Especifica un separador agregado entre las cadenas durante la unión.
- String1. Primera cadena a ser unida.
- String2. Segunda cadena a ser unida.

Para mayor información apoyate con la funciones String de MySQL.

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html
>
> http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat_ws-function.php

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo utilizar la palabra reservada AS para evitar confusiones y mantener las buenas prácticas, así como puedes hacer una concatenación de los campos de la siguiente forma `CONCAT("hr_timesheet_sheet_sheet"."date_to", " ", "hr_timesheet_sheet_sheet"."date_from") AS "FULL"`

Comment: Gracias por el consejo! Lo he aplicado! ;)